# Allow unstable Android Gradle builds on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-testing, build.gradle

Hi I have set up my Android project on Jenkins to provide CI. Its working well, running tests on a connected Android handset. The tests run on the Android Test Framework which extends jUnit3.

Unfortunately, the build is marked as a failure if there are any test failures. I'd like to be able to improve this in two ways:

1. Allowing unstable builds
2. Being able to mark known test failures

For item 1 I tried adding this to the project build.gradle:

```
connectedCheck {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

But it has no effect. Looking at the build log, I realised the actual test task is called connectedInstrumentTest, but this task is not found:

```
connectedInstrumentTest {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

causes:

> Could not find method connectedInstrumentTest() for arguments [build_4ldpah0qgf0ukktofecsq41r98$_run_closure3@9cd826] on project ':Playtime'.

That am I missing?

Thanks

EDIT: Heres my project build.gradle, nothing special:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
        testPackageName "com.bb.pt.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
}

connectedCheck {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

My gradle settings in jenkins:

```
switches: --stacktrace --info
tasks: :pt:assembleDebug :pt:assembleTest :pt:connectedCheck
```

EDIT:

I built gradlew and tried that. Same output. I don't want the build to FAIL if there are test failures:

```
:pt:connectedInstrumentTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':pt:connectedInstrumentTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/simon/WorkingCopies/bb/code/trunk/pt/pt/build/reports/instrumentTests/connected/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I tried to qualify the task name in build.gradle:

```
task connectedCheck {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

But it thinks I am trying to add a new task rather than modify the existing one.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/simon/WorkingCopies/bb/code/trunk/pt/pt/build.gradle' line: 31

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':pt'.
> Cannot add task ':pt:connectedCheck' as a task with that name already exists.
```

Comment: 1. you use some free style jobs right ? 2. what is your gradle command ? 3. have you tried gradle -debug ... ?

Comment: @coffeebreaks 1) nope, just the jobs set up by android plugin. 2) details of gradle posted above, 3) --debug didnt seem to help, just more info about other things.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer your question but I would recommend you look  into using Genymotion.  This is an emulator that works and is actually faster than testing on a device.  Unfortunately my Jenkin's builds are  still running based on the emulator and maven so I cant give you specifics yet

Comment: @Simon 1) to be clear, the android gradle plugin is attached to a gradle build ran by the Jenkins gradle plugin connected to a freestyle jenkins job. 2) you don't say if you run gradle or the gradle wrapper. Have you tried both ? 3) not sure what your :pt: prefixes are. 4) I would recommend you to run your gradle command outside of jenkins, from the same machine (because of your connected device requirements), with the --debug option, maybe just gradle --debug connectedCheck or gradlew --debug connectedCheck and check what kind of exit code you get.

Comment: @coffeebreaks THanks for the advice. I tried gradlew, same problem. Output is identical. The pt prefixes are the project name "pt". I get the same result running from the command line, rather than jenkins. BUILD FAILED because 1 test failed. I want BUILD SUCCEEDED then junit can mark it as unstable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After our conversation I believe that:

- the problem is gradle configuration only and not jenkins related. Get it to work in gradle.
- in gradle I believe (though I am not an expert) you should get the connectedInstrumentTest to ignore failures, but your attempt to use the following failed

  ```
  connectedInstrumentTest {
      ignoreFailures = true
  }
  ```
- maybe the solution is to wrap this config node like this:

  ```
  project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    connectedInstrumentTest {
      ignoreFailures = true
    }
  }
  ```

https://github.com/stanfy/hotandroid/blob/master/part0/build.gradle

Comment: Your solution to wrap the config node works! Many thanks! I have an unstable build (not necessarily anything to be proud of!). I take it this defers the config until the whole dependency graph is built?

Comment: @SimonPickles Yup. It looks like gradle has a more dynamic config than maven: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Comment: This doesn't change anything for me, the build is still in failure (exit code=1) when I apply your solution. Do you have other hints?
(I'm using Gradle 0.6.+ with Android SDK version 19 and build tools v. 19.0.0)

Comment: I had to use : connectedInstrumentTestDefaultFlavorDebug

Comment: I get could not find connectedInstrumentTest and connectedInstrumentTestDefaultFlavorDebug so this solution is not working anymore :(

Comment: Since Google updated the task name, the latest format should be like that:
connectedAndroidTest[YourFlavor][Debug].
If you are working on a flavor (such as demo, paid, etc.), you should include the flavor in the task name (camel case).

Comment: The syntax changed again, now it's `connected[Flavor][BuildType]AndroidTest`